# High level Architecture of SQL database

Tags: android, mysql, sql, database-design

I am constructing an SQLite database to store data on chess games for my multiplayer android chess app. I will eventually create a MySQL remote database for networking purposes so keep that in mind.

Given that thousands of users (hopefully) will be playing thousands of games in total, should I have a table per user? But I'd like to store games between two people in one place so shouldn't I have 1 table per game?

Also, I'd like to have a record of the moves in each game so would it make sense, if we're going with the one game one table model, to have each row correspond to the state of the board following a given move?

I'm a complete newcomer to coding in general and SQL databases in particular. Does my overall strategy seem reasonable?

Comment: 'should I have a table per user' _shudder_ God no, do **not** create tables per individual user

Comment: 1. why it has android tag? 2. *should I have a table per user?* of course not 3. *1 table per game* no ... 3 tables: users, games, rounds/turns(if you use rounds/turns)

Comment: ah, one more thing ... did you check google play services (games API)? ...

Answer (score 2):

Overall, I would say your design is completely wrong.

When designing a database, table's should be much more generalised (i.e. `table_users` rather than `table_user_1`, `table_user_2` etc). Otherwise your database will become almost unusable instantaneously through increased complexity.

I suggest you checkout some MySQL tutorials ([here](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SQL_Tutorial), [here](http://arachnoid.com/MySQL/) and [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/)) to see how databases are designed and work.

As a basic structure, I would create `users`, `games` and `moves` as tables and then have them link to each other using [foreign keys](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)